# How to intercept the response from REST API in case of 403 http status, in Spring class AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have the following problem: I customize the AuthenticationProvider class, provided by spring boot, to call a rest service in order to make the login on remote server.

If the credentials are correct, no problem.

The problem arises when the credentials are incorrect, and the server response http status is 403.
In practice, I can not get the response, because it is automatically raised an exception of API rest:

```
ResponseEntity <UserResponse> resp = restTemplate.exchange (url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, UserResponse.class);
```

I tried to create custom class, to catch the exception with
@ControllerAdvice annotation, But it can not be called because the exception does not arise in a controller but in AuthenticationProvider class.

Is there a way to intercept response of a rest API exception?

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

@Value("${search.login}")
private String searchLogin;

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

private DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    User user=new User();
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
    String json="log-> ";
    UserResponse response=new UserResponse();
    try {

                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                URI url;
                url = new URI(searchLogin);
                MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
                map.add("username",URLEncoder.encode(authentication.getName(), "utf-8"));
                map.add("password",URLEncoder.encode(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), "utf-8"));
                HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
                List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes=new ArrayList<MediaType>();
                acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
                requestHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map,requestHeaders);
                ResponseEntity<UserResponse> resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, UserResponse.class);
                response = resp.getBody();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to *do*? You say that you can't "get the response"--where? For what purpose? Looks like you're getting a correct (403) response just fine--what, specifically, do you want to be different?

Comment: Yes, I get correct 403, but I would like to read response and print it on log. But exception arise before and handled by spring framework and I can't read response.

Comment: when  you get 403 , then  you can determine the exception is happened and print it to log . is it ? or you can try and catch the exception and throw it again , combine with @ExcepionHandler , maybe it can work.

Comment: I need json response attached to 403 status not expation msg only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will have to handle it from Spring Security as @ControllerAdvice only intercepts exceptions being thrown directly from your controller. I think [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/) will give you the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Yes this should be correct answer if it was called rest service from a controller, but I'm in the AuthenticationProvider class, before any controller was called

Answer (score -1):

your can  try add @ExceptionHandler in your Rest . just like e.g. 
    `@ExceptionHandler
    public String exp(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {

//balabala 
}`

Comment: This will not work, as ControllerAdvice / ExceptionHandler only work with exceptions being thrown directly by the controller